# Meteor.js: How to perform action on download link of CollectionFS

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, collectionfs

Hello I have a template where I have link to download uploaded images:

```
{{#each uploads}}
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">{{original.name}} <a href="{{url download=true}}" class="btn btn-primary downloadUpload" data-uploadid="{{_id}}">Download</a></li>
            </ul>
{{/each}}
```

The link works normally however today I wanted to perform some actions once the button is clicked, like this:

```
Template.practicalQuestionTake.events
    'click .downloadUpload': (e, template) ->
        console.log @
```

But after add that event handler once I click the download link I can download the file however the page breaks (blank page), checking the logs in the console it shows me the error:

```
"TypeError: router.route is undefined"
```

Then I tried to return true:

```
Template.practicalQuestionTake.events
    'click .downloadUpload': (e, template) ->
        console.log @
        true
```

But same result, then I tried to use preventDefault

```
Template.practicalQuestionTake.events
    'click .downloadUpload': (e, template) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log @
```

And now anything happens, I can't download the file and it seems that nothing happens.

How can I perform some actions in the event handler of a download link of CollectionFS?

Comment: Could you post a code sample of your client code where the `router.route is undefined` error is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I did a lot of research, and then found that the problem is an issue of Iron router, for some reason when you have a link that points to an external url all your subscriptions and data contexts are lost so you get a 404 not found page or "TypeError: router.route is undefined"

[This is the issue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/472) The solution to this problem: Whenever you have a download link (Amazon S3, dropbox, CollectionFS, etc) use `target="_blank"` in your link. That sovled my issue =)